# how to call this function which requires self parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters, self

I'm trying to test one function which returns the CLD features..
it only requires use numpy library.. I'm testing it but it always says that requires a `self` parameter. I don't know why it is happening because the function only is receiving one image which I'm loading with opencv.

Here is the class that I'm trying to use:
[colorlayoutdescriptor.py](https://github.com/alcarazolabs/CLDescriptor/blob/master/colorlayoutdescriptor.py)

```
import numpy as np

class ColorLayoutDescriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rows = 8
        self.cols = 8
        self.prefix = "CLD"

    def compute(self, img):
        averages = np.zeros((self.rows,self.cols,3))
```

I expect to send one image to the method called `compute` and get one feature vector, now I'm getting this problem::

```
image = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
vector = ColorLayoutDescriptor.compute(image)
```

> TypeError: compute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img'

thanks so much.

Comment: You want `ColorLayoutDescriptor().compute(image)`.

Comment: thanks man.. i could access to the method of the class with that way.. but now i'm getting this message: slice = img[imgH/self.rows * row: imgH/self.rows * (row+1), imgW/self.cols*col : imgW/self.cols*(col+1)]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: Please edit your question instead. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @Vincent if you have another issue, then post another question.

Comment: that's ok dears..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColorLayoutDescriptor is a class, so you first have to create an instance of the class:

```
cld = ColorLayoutDescriptor()
cld.compute(image)
```

Comment: That work perfectly.. but now i'm getting this message:   slice = img[imgH/self.rows * row: imgH/self.rows * (row+1), imgW/self.cols*col : imgW/self.cols*(col+1)]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
The original class is it: https://github.com/scferrada/imgpedia/blob/master/IMGdescriptors/Python/ColorLayoutComputer.py I deleted this parameter ColorLayoutComputer(DescriptorComputer):  because is unnecessary.. is for that the error?

Comment: It seems that @fluxens has answered your question satisfactorily. If you have another question please feel free to ask it as a separate question.